# iOS UIbutton weird bottom edge

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm just encountering a weird border for the UIbutton. I've added a button in the xib file and I've set for it an image but after running the project on the simulator it looked like this:
[image: Screenshot of the simulator]

I haven't changed any property of that button and I haven't touched it in the code.
Does anyone know why it is looking like this? and how can I solve it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDITED:

This is the image used for that button:
[image: image of the button]

Comment: Did you set the type to custom in the button properties in interface builder?

Comment: Looks to me like there's a thin grey line at the bottom of your button image.

Comment: I can clearly see a thin gray line at the bottom of your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, try this image. I've removed the thin gray line from the bottom. It should fix your gray line :-)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The image has a gray line on the bottom of it. Here it is blown up in Photoshop, with a red background added.

[image]